# Check if row exist in datagridview, if not then insert new row c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to call data from SQL database and show in datagirview, everything is ok until now, but I want to update qty in datagridview column for 1, after I call new data and the row exist in datagridview, if data don't exist in datagridview then add new row. The condition to check if the row exist, could be the barcode or index[0]

I use this code to call data

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("calldata", com);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", Convert.ToInt64(txtbarcode.Text));
//Created a new DataTable
txtbarcode.Text = "";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
dtgproduct.DataSource = dataTable.DefaultView;

com.Close();


com.Open();//Open the SQL connection

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();//Create a SqlDataReader

while (reader.Read())//For each row that the SQL query returns do
{
    DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();//Create new DataRow to populate the DataTable (which is currently binded to the DataGrid)
    dr[0] = reader[0];//Fill DataTable column 0 current row (Product) with reader[0] (Product from sql)
    dr[1] = reader[1];
    dr[2] = reader[2];
    dr[3] = reader[3];
    dr[4] = reader[4];
    dr[5] = reader[5];


    dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Thanks to everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
```

Then you can just rely on your SQL call to prevent duplicate rows.